# How to jump to next page using crawlspider?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm scraping http://www.sephora.com/lipstick using scrapy crawlspider. 
How should I set up `LinkExtractor` in order to scrap all pages?`

```
class SephoraSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = "sephora"
# custom_settings = {"IMAGES_STORE": '../images/sephora'}

# allowed_domains = ["sephora.com/"]

start_urls = [
    'http://www.sephora.com/lipstick'
    # 'http://www.sephora.com/eyeshadow',
    # 'http://www.sephora.com/foundation-makeup'
]

rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(
            # restrict_xpaths='//*[@id="main"]/div[4]/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[7]',
            allow=('sephora.com/')
            ), 
        callback = 'parse_items',
        follow =True),)

def parse(self,response):
    # category = ['lipstick']
    # for cat in category:
    full_url = 'http://www.sephora.com/rest/products/?currentPage=1&categoryName=lipstick&include_categories=true&include_refinements=true'
    my_request = scrapy.Request(full_url, callback = 'parse_items')
    my_request.meta['page'] = {'to_replace':"currentPage=1"}
    yield my_request

def parse_items(self,response):

    # cat_json = response.xpath('//script[@id="searchResult"]/text()').extract_first()
    # all_url_data = json.loads(cat_json.encode('utf-8'))
    # if "products" not in all_url_data:
    #     return
    # products = all_url_data['products']
    products = json.loads(response.body)['products']
    print(products)
    for each_product in products:
        link = each_product['product_url']
        full_url = "http://www.sephora.com"+link
        name = each_product["display_name"]
        if 'list_price' not in each_product['derived_sku']:
            price = each_product['derived_sku']['list_price_max']
        else:
            price = each_product['derived_sku']["list_price"]
        brand = each_product["brand_name"]
        item = ProductItem(
            name=name,
            price=price,
            brand=brand,
            full_url=full_url,
            category=response.url[23:])
        yield item

    to_replace = response.meta['page']['to_replace']
    cat = response.meta['page']['category']
    next_number = int(to_replace.replace("currentPage=", "")) + 1
    next_link = response.url.replace(
        to_replace, "currentPage=" + str(next_number))
    print(next_link)
    my_request = scrapy.Request(
        next_link,
        self.parse_items)
    my_request.meta['page'] = {
        "to_replace": "currentPage=" + str(next_number),

    }
    yield my_request
```

I have this error now.

```
    2017-06-12 12:43:30 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.sephora.com/rest/products/?currentPage=1&categoryName=lipstick&include_categories=true&include_refinements=true> (referer: http://www.sephora.com/makeup-cosmetics)
2017-06-12 12:43:30 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://www.sephora.com/rest/products/?currentPage=1&categoryName=lipstick&include_categories=true&include_refinements=true> (referer: http://www.sephora.com/makeup-cosmetics)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Lee/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 45, in mustbe_deferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/Users/Lee/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 48, in process_spider_input
    return scrape_func(response, request, spider)
  File "/Users/Lee/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/scraper.py", line 145, in call_spider
    dfd.addCallbacks(request.callback or spider.parse, request.errback)
  File "/Users/Lee/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 299, in addCallbacks
    assert callable(callback)
AssertionError
2017-06-12 12:43:30 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Don't.

Long answer: I'd do it differently.The pagination links do not return a new page. Instead they send a `GET`-request to this URL:

`http://www.sephora.com/rest/products/?currentPage=2&categoryName=lipstick&include_categories=true&include_refinements=true`.

Check your networks tab and click on a pagination link: [image: Networks-Tab]

Here you can see the request and the response your browser makes. In this case, clicking a paginatino link yields a JSON-object which contains all the products displayed on the page.

Now check out the `Response`-tab of the request. Under `products` you can see numbers from 0 to 59, which are the products displayed on the page, as well as all the information on the products, such as `id`, `display_name` and, oh, `url`.

Try right-clicking on the request and selecting `Open in a new tab` to see the response in your browser. Now try setting the `items per page` on the sephora-homepage to something different. You see what happens? The JSON-object returns fewer or more items now (depending on what you chose).

So what do we do with this information now?

Ideally, we would be able to request the JSON-object for each page (by simmply changing the request url from `current_page=2` to `current_page=3`) directly in our spider and follow the URLS provided there (under `products/n-product/product_url` and then crawl the individual objects (or just extract the product lists if that's what you want).

Luckily, Scrapy (better, Python) allows you to parse JSON-objects and do anything you want with the parsed data. And luckily Sephora lets you choose to display all items per page which changes the request-url to `?pageSize=-1`.

What you do is `yield` a request to the url that yields the JSON-object and define a `parse`-function that processes the object.

Just a quick example that will extract the urls for each product and yield a request to this url (I will try do provide a more detailed example later):

```
import json

data = json.loads(response.body)
for product in data["products"]:
    url = response.urljoin(product["product_url"])
    yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_products)
```

There you have it. It really pays of the learn to yield requests to a website, as you can easily manipulate the request url to make your life easier. For example, you could change the `categoryName` in the URL to parse another category.

Comment: I just added my code to scraping products. If i keep this function and change it to parse_products, I need to add parse_start_url that deals with http://www.sephora.com/rest/products/?currentPage=1&categoryName=lipstick&include_categories=true&include_refinements=true , right?

Comment: Correct, you'll basically need a parse-function that generates the request to the json-object, one that parses it and one that handles the individual product-urls.

Comment: I just changed my code but it doesn't seem to work, not even the first page

Comment: From a quick look: You need to rename `parse_start_urls` to `parse` only, this is the first parse-function that scrapy looks for. Plus you need to actually `yield` your request in the parse-function. Right now, you are only defining the request and populating it with meta information.

Comment: Also, does start_url need to change?

Comment: You need to configure 'allowed_domains'. Check the [docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=allowed_domains#scrapy.spiders.Spider.allowed_domains)

Comment: I deleted allowed_domains, and the offsite error was gone. But there's another callable error. I updated my code and error above. What does it mean?